# sort by date with sum clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  name  |        date       |  count  |  balance  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
    1       a        0000-00-00          1          10
    2       b        2014-10-02          1          20
    3       c        2014-09-01          1          30
    4       d        2014-09-16          1          40
```

I need to get the `SUM` of the four `count` & `balance` column on my `SELECT`, then order it by the `date` in ascending but I need to make sure it should not be the `0000-00-00`. I tried this syntax but it does not order the date the way I wanted.

```
SELECT 
date,
SUM(count) AS deposit_counts, 
SUM(balance) AS balance_sum
FROM tbl
ORDER BY date ASC
```

My expected output:

```
-------------------------------------------
|        date       |  count  |  balance  |
-------------------------------------------
     2014-09-01          4          90
```

Comment: And the output should be?

Comment: Why the date field in the expected result is `2014-09-01` and not, say, `2014-10-10`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - I don't get you buddy. `2014-09-01` because it is the most earlier date and that is what I wanted to get the earlier date along with sum of all the result.

Comment: Please clarify. You need the earliest valid date and the sums of all records including the one with the invalid date. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use MIN and NULLIF functions:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(NULLIF(date, '0000-00-00')) AS min_date,
  SUM(count) AS deposit_counts, 
  SUM(balance) AS balance_sum
FROM tbl
```

Test it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d43acf/1

Comment: Working however not portable to CodeIgniter's Active Record.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I understood the point in having a 0000-00-00 date as opposed to having null so only one possibility needs ruling out... Anyway at first I would assume you might want to get the total balances of each day and would require a query along these lines

```
SELECT
    date,
    sum(count) AS deposit_counts,
    SUM(balance) AS balance_sum
FROM tbl
WHERE date <> '0000-00-00'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

which would output

```
2014-09-01          1          30
2014-09-16          1          40
2014-10-02          1          20
```

but as it stands it appears you don't, I'm not one hundred percent sure what your ultimate goal is in terms of future querying so I will guess you want a historical value of balances up to the current date, ruling out the weird zero date thing. In which case you might want a greater than WHERE clause, and presumably just the lowest value in the date column to show the total from this date like so:

```
SELECT
    min(date) AS date,
    sum(count) AS deposit_counts,
    SUM(balance) AS balance_sum
FROM tbl
WHERE date > '0000-00-00'
```

since it would ignore the invalid date it will return

```
2014-09-01          3          80
```

I hope this is of some use.

Edit:

if you absolutely require all values then you will want to use a subquery to retrieve and rule out the exceptional date result like so:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT min(date) FROM tbl WHERE date > '0000-00-00') AS date,
    sum(count) AS deposit_counts,
    SUM(balance) AS balance_sum
FROM tbl
```

or as above, nullif on your date query should work too